# I cant add object to realm with primary key

Tags: reactjs, typescript, realm

I have this kind of object:

```js
export default class Route {
    public id: number = 0;
    public name: string = "";
    public points: Point[] = []

    public static schema: Realm.ObjectSchema = {
        name: 'Route',
        primaryKey: 'id',
        properties: {
            id: 'int',
            name: 'string',
            points: { type: 'list', objectType: 'Point' },
        }
    }
}
```

So, when i tried to add this object to realm db i've got such error: **Cannot modify primary key after creation: 'Route.id'**

```js
realm.write(() => {
    let id = realm.objects(Route.schema.name).length + 1;
    let route = realm.create<Route>(Route.schema.name, {
        id: id,
        name: `Route ${id}`,
        points: [],
    });
});
```

So, what i missed?